# Where can I learn about finding explicit formulas of period integrals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, abelian-varieties

I want to learn about how to compute explicit examples of jacobians of curves, but I'm not sure where to start. Every source I've found either only discusses elliptic curves, or general theory without reference to tools for explicit computations. There are a few basic cases which I would like to know how to do computations with

```
(1) smooth hyperelliptic curves
(2) smooth plane curves
(3) smooth complete intersection curves
```